# Security of hash functions over input extended with a random value

Tags: hash, birthday-attack

Hashing a single message say $H(M)$ is vulnerable to a birthday attack.
But what if a combination is hashed, such has $H(M,R)$? Is it still vulnerable to the attack?

I think it is because $M, R$ can be assumed to be as $X$, so in essence $H(X)$ is being hashed and the birthday attack possibility still exists. Is this logic correct?

Comment: Why shouldn't this logic be correct?

Comment: Well, I was wondering if there was any other perspective to approach this problem.

Comment: That problem can be modeled as [randomized hashing](http://webee.technion.ac.il/~hugo/rhash/rhash.pdf). ​ For candidate-eTCR hashes, the analogue of the birthday attack requires that the adversary _submit lots of messages to honest parties_, rather than just do offline computation. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 2):

> I think so cause $M, R$ can be assumed to be as $X$, so in essence $H(X)$ is being hashed and the birthday attack possibility still exists.

Yes, that's correct.

Note that there is no such function as $H(M, R)$, you'd need some way of combining the values; lets assume concatenation though (so $H(M | R)$).

Comment: Concatenation of variable-length input is a bad idea in general, tho. For a message $110$ and random value $11$, I can find a collision with the message $11$ and random value $011$.

Comment: True, this was just for sake of answering the question though. You could use an ASN1 SEQUENCE and DER encoding instead.